# Как получить открытые вкладки в браузере с JavaScript/JQ

Tags: javascript

Есть ли способ получить список URL открытых вкладок в браузере средствами JavaScript/JQ ?

Comment: уточните, вы находясь на своем сайте, хотите получить список всех открытых вкладок пользователя? Или речь не про сайт, а про плагины браузеров, или список не всех вкладок, а всех своих вкладок? Как вы думаете, с точки зрения безопасности и приватности, кто нибудь в здравом уме позволит вам просмотреть весь список вкладок целиком?

Comment: это можно сделать только с помощью broser api которое доступно в расширениях для браузера